# How can i specify headers as application/json using JSONDOC

Tags: java, spring, webservice-client, jsondoc

I am using Spring4 to design my REST API. But while I am documenting it using JsonDoc, it is giving me an error as:

> The server refused this request because the request entity is in a
>   format not supported by the requested resource for the requested
>   method.
>
> #### Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.62
>
> ",   "status": 415,   "statusText":
>   "Unsupported Media Type" }

```
@ApiMethod
@ApiHeaders(headers={ @ApiHeader(name="Content-Type", allowedvalues="application/json",description="application/json")})
@RequestMapping(value="/test" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)   
public @ApiResponseObject  @ResponseBody ResponseMessage test(@ApiBodyObject @RequestBody TestDto test){
    System.out.println(test.getId());
    return testService.addTestMessage("hello demo");
}
```

How can I test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your content type and check your payload format.

There might be some attribute which are not matching.

Comment: Yes you r right... The above answer by @Vijay  resolves my problem already ..anyway your response also correct

Answer (score 0):

I believe It has nothing to do with JSONDoc. You need to check if you are sending valid Content-Type like application/json.

Please also check TestDto JSON representation is correctly converting to JAVA object. Spring throws this error if your JSON string is not able to convert java object.

> If you are using Jackson API, You can use below sample to get exception
>   and see cause.

```
    String myJsonString="Your JSON String";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.readValue(myJsonString,TestDto.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```